# How to model this many-many relation in Database?

Tags: sql-server

We have two tables ManagementPlan which tells what type of product model has to be used.Based on this model number, a particular product of that type is assigned to a patient during therapy session.How can we model the many-many relation between Product table and ManagementPlan table

```
MangamentPlan(
  PlanID(PK),
  DiagnosisID(FK),
  PhysicianID(FK),
  PMCModelID,
  Objective,
  Description,
  DateTime
)

Product(
  PMCProductID(PK),
  ManuProductID(FK),
  ManufacturerID(FK),
  PMCModelID,
  Manufacturer model,
  Features description,
  PurchaseDate,
  Storage Location
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a junction table:

```
ManagementPlanProduct(PlanID(PK, FK(ManagementPlan)), PMCProductID(PK, FK(Product)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a junction table

```
ManagementPlanProduct (
    PlanID (PK, FK)
    PMCProductID (PK, FK)
)
```

```
CREATE TABLE ManagementPlanProduct (
    PlanID int NOT NULL,
    PMCProductID int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_mpp PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PlanID, PMCProductID)
);

ALTER TABLE ManagementPlanProduct
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_mpp_mp
FOREIGN KEY (PlanID) REFERENCES ManagementPlan (PlanID)
ON DELETE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE ManagementPlanProduct
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_mpp_p
FOREIGN KEY (PMCProductID) REFERENCES Product (PMCProductID)
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

You can also add other columns to the junction table like quantity, date added, sort order and so on.